# SQL Server Management Data Warehouse creates a lot of sleeping user connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, management, management-data-warehouse

I am wondering if someone already experience this weird scenario regarding my SQL Server Management Data Warehouse; it creates a lot of user connections. Around 2500 connections which were all sleeping.

When I turned off the data collector, all the connections were disconnected but I am wondering what the problem is supposed to be.

My MDW Repo is running under SQL 2014 and is getting around 100+ instances.
The server that I am having a problem with is running SQL Server 2012 SP2 CU 12.